# Get application cookie time remaining

Tags: javascript, c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

Using either JS or C# how can I retrieve the remaining time from the ExpireTimeSpan property?

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.Cookie.Name = "auth";
        });
```

Comment: @vasily.sib That information is 10 years old and very outdated. Even ASP.NET Core 1.0 documentation is completely incompatible 2.0 docs. Furthermore, session and auth application cookies are different. That is my dilemma. I can't find out how to get the ExpireTimeSpan property value. Additionally, if you inspect the cookie in the browser the date is set to 1969, instead of one hour later, however, the expiration time is being respected.

Comment: oh, I see now, that we are talking about authentication. Then look at `User` property of controller. There should by a `Claim` "ExpireAt" or something like that. Anyway, why do you think that date in cookie is set to 1969? Can you show as an actual value of that field?

Comment: You're using a sliding expiration, so effectively, the time remaining is always one hour from now (your expiration timespan), since you could only check this as part of a user request. That request would reset the timer.

Comment: @ChrisPratt It only resets if it is at least 30 mins old